# GEA3 direction clarification

Tags: encryption, gsm

GEA3 (and 4) stands for GPRS Encryption Algorithm. It's specified in 3GPP TS 55.216 (at least used to, until some idiot forced them to hide it because of "export restrictions" or some crap like that). One of the parameters for generating gamma using GEA3 is 1-bit "direction" value which represents either MS to SGSN (or opposite) traffic. Surprisingly none of the specs I've seen says explicitly which value corresponds to which direction. So, what exactly is direction 0 and what is 1 in GEA3 and GEA4?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! The MS -> SGSN is 0, SGSN -> MS is 1: they have put it into appendix - probably just to make it easier to find.